# why Jenkins promoting instrumented jar to my repository

Tags: maven, jenkins, cobertura, maven-cobertura-plugin

I have an issue that Jenkins promoting an instrumented jar file to nexus repository, so when it deploy my application in jBoss in throwing exception `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sourceforge/cobertura/coveragedata/TouchCollector
    at com.premierinc.its.pfgpgrouper.service.algorithms.AbstractPopulationGrouper.__cobertura_init`

Jenkins maven configuration:
version is mvn-3.2.3
clean install site

my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.myapp.its</groupId>
<artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
<version>15.2.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>MyApp</name>
<description>
   MY API.
</description>

<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:ssh://git@code/pfpg/my-app.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://git@code/pfgp/my-app.git</developerConnection>
    <tag>HEAD</tag>
</scm>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>code-artifacts</id>
        <url>
            http://code/artifacts/content/repositories/releases
        </url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>code-artifacts</id>
        <url>
            http://code/artifacts/content/repositories/snapshots
        </url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>

<properties>
    <spring.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <oracle.version>11.2.0.2.0</oracle.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.15</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>-Xms512m -Xmx512m</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <formats>
                    <format>xml</format>
                    <format>html</format>
                </formats>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>site</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>cobertura</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jgitflow-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-alpha21.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                <pushFeatures>true</pushFeatures>
                <pushHotfixes>true</pushHotfixes>
                <pushReleases>true</pushReleases>
                <noReleaseBuild>true</noReleaseBuild>
                <noFeatureBuild>true</noFeatureBuild>
                <noHotfixBuild>true</noHotfixBuild>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>myFile</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/schema</schemaDirectory>
                        <outputDirectory>src/main/java/</outputDirectory>
                        <extension>true</extension>
                        <arguments>
                            -no-header -cp collection-setter-injector.jar
                            -Xcollection-setter-injector
                        </arguments>
                        <packageName>com.premierinc.its.pfgpgrouper.dto</packageName>
                        <staleFile>
                            ${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/jaxb/patient/.staleFlag
                        </staleFile>

                        <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.java.dev.vcc.thirdparty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>collection-setter-injector</artifactId>
                    <version>0.5.0-1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

        </plugin>

    </plugins>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>


</build>


<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- <plugin> <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId> 
            <version>2.10.1</version> </plugin> -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <formats>
                    <format>html</format>
                    <format>xml</format>
                </formats>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.13</version>
            <configuration>
                <configLocation>src/code-analysis/checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</reporting>

<dependencies>
    <!-- DB Driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6g</artifactId>
        <version>${oracle.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SPRING -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-mock</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.8</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>5.14.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>axis</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.19</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm running into the same issue; Maven 3.2.3, cobertura-maven-plugin 2.7, Jenkins 1.608. This seems to be a Jenkins issue rather than a cobertura issue.

My jenkins job runs the maven goals `clean verify site:site` on the main build step.

Jenkins then deploys the artifact generated during `verify` to the maven repository, however, the classes in the jar are all instrumented by Cobertura, resulting in `NoClassDefFoundErrors` at runtime, as the Java EE container doesn't know the Cobertura classes.

I tried to add the maven call `clean package` as post-build step, but that didn't change anything - Jenkins somehow saves the artifact built in the main step and only deploys this, ignoring artifacts built in post-build steps.

What works for me for now is to disable Jenkins' "deploy artifacts" option altogether and have it run a post-build `mvn clean deploy` instead. However, you'll have to add `-DskipTests=true`, otherwise all your unit and integration test will be run a second time.

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with cobertura which they have fixed in latest release,  please refer this [link](https://github.com/cobertura/cobertura/issues/52).

Comment: Thank you @ManojP, I saw this earlier and I don't think that as the issue and if it is the issue there is a more serious issue out there, that is cobertura just for doing the coverage instrumenting the packaged jar or instrumenting the classes and later packaging. As per the maven life cycle 'clean install site' has to do the packaging before it enters site and instrumentation only happens at site. so there should be a package created without instrumented classes and that is the one I expect at my repository. I don't want to run an instrumented code in my server.